# What to do with this tailwindcss Runtime error, which may not depend on tailwindcss itself?

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, vite, nuxtjs3

```
[vite-node] [plugin:vite:css] [@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities; ] /assets/css/tailwind.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nFqf.png)

Perhaps this error when building the project has something to do with the tailwindcss problem.
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9r1M.png)

---

### [Error repordodction](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/representation-error-zytvo2?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A19%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A19%2C%22startColumn%22%3A19%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A19%7D%5D)

I'm stuck on this problem, I can't remember what I did with the project to get this error, it all started with the fact that I reinstall tailwindcss module when I wanted to switch to something else, but decided to go back, and after some other changes in packages, maybe because of the update from Nuxt 3.3.1 to 3.4.0 started some errors, but the most important thing is that when I rolled back the project to a previous version where there was no this error and everything was working fine and this error still remains, when I have several times rechecked all stages of installation and configuration tailwindcss.

##### Thank you!

Comment: you need to share some more code. What you added in the "Error repordodction" is not enough. There is no relevant CSS or JS code in there that I can see

Comment: I did it. @CornelRaiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to localize my problem! It's all about the wrong tailwind.config syntax.
[problem plugin code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mpUN.png)

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
module.exports = plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
  addVariant({
    pointing: ['@media (min-width: 1024px) &:hover', '&:focus-within'],
  })
})
```

Right code:

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
module.exports = plugin(function ({ addVariant }) {
    addVariant('pointing', [
        '@media (min-width: 1024px) &:hover',
        '&:focus-within',
    ])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've read your code and I will give you some suggestions I hope they will be work.
First of all, reinstall your node-module. Secondly, try this code in your nuxt.config.ts, because I saw that you add modules in it but you don't add css:[] in there try this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css'], 
});
```

and I suggest that remove this section from your nuxt.config.ts:

```
  tailwindcss: {
   configPath: "~/tailwind.config.js",
},
```

if you have to write it do it in this way:

```
postcss: {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  },
},
```

I hope these pieces of advice will help your issue, and write tailwind document on nuxt3.